# Can't get pagination to work with Jekyll in /archive/ directory

Tags: jekyll, jekyll-paginator

I've gone through the previous questions about Jekyll and pagination and none of the suggestions are working.  I have this:

```
_config.yml
gems:
  - jekyll-paginate
paginate: 5 # amount of posts to show
paginate_path: archive/page:num/

archive.html
---
 layout: archive
 permalink: /archive/
 author_profile: true
---
{% include base_path %}

<h3 class="archive__subtitle">{{ site.data.ui-text[site.locale].recent_posts }}</h3>

{% for post in paginator.posts %}
  {% include archive-single.html %}
{% endfor %}

{% include paginator.html %}
```

This ends up with a very nicely formatted archive page in /archive/ with zero posts.  My posts do have permalinks, I don't know if that's the problem.  The subdirectories are being created correctly but the archive page just doesn't find them.

Note that if I put it in index.html that works great, but I want to have a splash page at the front with a link to an archive page for posts, which seems possible but just doesn't work.

Please don't call this a duplicate.  I've read the other 10 posts on the same thing, and for some reason it's just not working.

This is Jekyll 3.1.6

Comment: I'd suggest you build the site with a handful of posts only and remove the permalink from these posts. They clearly state in the documentation that permalinks breaks the pagination - https://jekyllrb.com/docs/pagination/

Comment: I removed permalinks from all posts and still have the same outcome.

Comment: Do you have the code available on GitHub? If not, can you reproduce the same behavior on a starter site (jekyll new sitename) and post code on GitHub?

Comment: https://github.com/synedra/minimal-mistakes - thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Was about to clone the repo now and saw you've changed to the `jekyll-archive` gem. Is it resolved, then?

Answer (score -2):

Switched to jeckyll-archives which solved the issue.

Comment: Could you elaborate? It looks like you are using the `jekyll-paginate` plugin in tandem with `jekyll-archive`, as I am. I can't get pagination to show up on archive pages. If you have a working example it would be greatly appreciated.